# Java 8 ForkJoinTask - main thread hangs even though child tasks complete successfully

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, java-8, fork-join

Why does the following never complete even though the sub-tasks do? The `miner.mine` does some DB inserts that I can see completed but the prompt never comes back.

```
private void run(Path path) {
    findAllFilesInDirectory(path).forEach(
        p -> ForkJoinTask.adapt(() -> miner.mine(p)).invoke());
}

private Stream<Path> findAllFilesInDirectory(final Path path) {
    try {
        return find(path, 1,
            (p, fileAttributes) -> fileAttributes.isRegularFile());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("There was an error processing path: {}.", path);

        return Stream.empty();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently creating the EntityManagerFactory as a static variable was causing this issue even if when DB operations were performed. Closing the EMF solved the problem but since the EMF is thread-safe (but the EntityManager isn't), there was no reason to create and close an EMF every time I accessed the DB. It could've been a Hibernate issue, I didn't investigate further. I switched to Spring Boot Data JPA instead.